# Geode: Serialization Exception & Could not create an instance of a class on server

Tags: geode

I have the client side working, looks like everything is alright. I can save the object and retrieve the object back from the client side.

However, if i am trying to use gfsh or data browser to view the data, i got this exception on gfsh

```
Message : Could not create an instance of a class com.room.backend.soa.spring.cache.geode.test.domain.Book
Result  : false
```

and on data browser

```
javalangException- Query could not be executed due to - orgapachegeodepdxPdxSerializationException- Could not create an instance of a class comroombackendsoaspringcachegeodetestdomainBook
```

My code is like this

```
    ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new ClientCacheFactoryBean();
    gemfireCache.setClose(true);
    gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties);
    gemfireCache.setPdxSerializer(pdxSerializer);
```

pdxSerializer is

```
    ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer serializer =
            new ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer(
                    "com.room.backend.soa.spring.cache.geode.test.domain.*",
                    "com.room.backend.soa.spring.cache.geode.test.domain.Book",
                    "com.room.backend.soa.spring.cache.geode.test.domain.Book#identity=id.*",
                    "com.room.backend.soa.spring.cache.geode.test.domain.#identity=id.*"

                    );
```

Comment: I think you have to register the pdx type in the cache like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793610/registering-pdx-type-in-type-registry-with-geode-c-sharp-native-client)

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `gfsh>configure pdx --read-serialized=true` command. This should be done after starting the locator, but before starting the servers. Please  refer to [this docs page](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/12/developing/data_serialization/use_pdx_high_level_steps.html) for details.

Comment: Exactly i have found out as well. Thanks. out of curiosity though, you know why the configure is not turned on by default ?

Comment: If you have installed callbacks on the server (CacheListeners/CacheWriters etc) you will have to work with PDXInstance in those callbacks rather than the domain objects. Since this an explicit decision that the user has to make, read-serialized is not turned on by default.